# Scroll animation where sections fade in on top of each other

Tags: javascript, css, animation, scroll

On a website with multiple sections (each have 100vw and at least 100vh) I would like to achieve an effect where whenever the user scrolls, instead of "moving" the dom upwards revealing further sections like a normal webpage would work, the following section would fade in on top of the previous. (exact opposite effect when scrolling upwards) I made a simple animation to illustrate the effect:

[image: Animation]

Now, since the sections would fade in **on top** of each other, they would all have to be absolutely positioned on the top of the page. That way, I could make only the current section visible and the rest hidden, changing the visibility as the user scrolls. This has some caveats though:

- How would the user trigger a scroll event if all the sections are positioned on top and they might not be larger than the viewport height?
- How would the scrollbar remain in its proper position based on the current section if again, everything is on the top?
- How would I show a regular layout without the fadein animations and absolutely postioned elements if the user had no javascript enabled.

The only sollution to all those problems I could come up with is to create identical copies of all the sections so that the copies could have a fixed position on top with the fadein animation. That way, the copies could be all invisible by default in case user has no javascript and the user would always be able to trigger scroll events, since there would always be the regular layout underneath and the fixed copies would be just an overlay. (this would also fix the scrollbar position issue). This isn't great however, since it creates some obvious performance issues and hinders DX quite significantly.

So, is there any way to achieve this particular effect without messy sollutions? Maybe there's a name for it so that I could look up how others did it because I feel like I've seen it before - just can't remember where.